# While making the maze game, it doesn't work in the process of setting the wall. (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, maze

**Player Motion Code (set to PICTURE BOX)**

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
            PlayerPictureBox.Left -= 10;
            return true;

        case Keys.Right:
            PlayerPictureBox.Left += 10;                      
            return true;

        case Keys.Up:
            PlayerPictureBox.Top -= 10;                        
            return true;

        case Keys.Down:      
            PlayerPictureBox.Top += 10;
            return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);            
}
```

**Make Maze Code**

```
public void LoadMaze()
{     
    for (int i = 0; i < XTILES; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < YTILES; j++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0 || j % 2 == 0)
            {
                mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.Black;                  
            }      
            else
            mazeTiles[i, j].BackColor = Color.White;
            mazeTiles[23, 23].BackColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
```

How do I prevent a player from going through a wall when he encounters a wall?

```
player = playerPictureBox;
Wall = mazeTiles[i,j].BackColor = Color.Black;
```

Comment: If the player overlaps a wall (see: bounding boxes) reset their position to the pre-wall position, or the edge of the wall.

Comment: We've tried that method, but it's very difficult to reset a maze that you set up in a two-dimensional array to a previous wall position.

Comment: you need a check method before you allow the keypress to have effect. First check if he can move in this direction. If not, then ignore the keypress. I don't see any reason for active position reset, If you simply can do *nothing*

Comment: Don't reset the maze, reset the player pos. I.e. (when moving left for instance) something like: `PlayerPictureBox.Left -= 10; if (CheckWallCollision()) PlayerPictureBox.Left += 10;`

Comment: I understand what you mean, but it is very difficult to check whether the location you are moving is a wall or not before you enter the direction key.

Comment: Why is it difficult? Why have you created a game where it's so difficult to compare the player's position to the level map?